GUFW Graphical Noise, Blurred Options
I installed GUFW but when I run it I have blurred options, buttons, graphical glitches and I can't select any option because I can't see anything.
enter image description here

You are probably missing dependencies.
Try:
sudo apt install --reinstall gufw --install-recommends
enter image description here
